# Australian Crime Data

Tags: data-request, crime, australia

Is there a place that I can get Australian crime data? I was hoping to get a database (or at least be able to crawl such a page) where it is in the format of: [date, incident, location].

The closest that I got to was the Institute of Criminology which has aggregated data and some figures http://www.aic.gov.au/statistics.html. There is also this map: http://crimetool.bocsar.nsw.gov.au/bocsar/ which is clearly querying some database, but I don't know of the API or where the database is.

Comment: for non-aggregate, incident-level data you may have better luck with individual police departments rather than national level agencies. http://data.gov.au/ may be a place to start

Comment: Did you ever get to any sort of API or the Crime Tool database, @sachinruk?

Answer (score 1):

For Vic -> https://www.crimestatistics.vic.gov.au/crime-statistics/latest-crime-data/download-data

Note that I wouldn't think they would release every incident with a location as some data would identify the Victim (e.g. The location of every sexual assault)

Answer (score 0):

For QLD there's an API to find where crime has occured in the last 5 years

https://www.data.qld.gov.au/dataset/crime-locations-2000-present